# How do I detect if the specific Delphi IDE is running?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2, version-detection

I'm working on a component installer (only for Delphi XE2) and I would like to detect if the Delphi XE2 IDE is running. How would you detect it?

P.S. I know about the `TAppBuilder` window class name, but I need to detect also the IDE version.

Comment: If you can find the window handle of the main window you can use GetWindowThreadProcessId to obtain the process id. Then call OpenProcess to get a process handle. Then call GetModuleFileNameEx to get hold of the exe file name. Then use GetFileVersionInfo etc. to read the exe file's version resource. Phew!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: :-) Take a deep breath, again, and again. There that should feel better.

Comment: I expect the above will do the job but I would not be in the least surprised if somebody could find an easier way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are the steps to determine if the Delphi XE2 is running

1) First Read the location of the the *bds.exe* file from the `App` entry in the `\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\9.0`  registry key which can be located in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE Root key.

2) Then using the [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function  you can  check if exist a exe with the same name running.

3) Finally using the PID of the last processed entry you can resolve the full file path of the Exe (using the [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function) and then compare the names again.

Check this sample code

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses

  Registry,
  PsAPI,
  TlHelp32,
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

function ProcessFileName(dwProcessId: DWORD): string;
var
  hModule: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := '';
  hModule := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, False, dwProcessId);
  if hModule <> 0 then
    try
      SetLength(Result, MAX_PATH);
      if GetModuleFileNameEx(hModule, 0, PChar(Result), MAX_PATH) > 0 then
        SetLength(Result, StrLen(PChar(Result)))
      else
        Result := '';
    finally
      CloseHandle(hModule);
    end;
end;

function IsAppRunning(const FileName: string): boolean;
var
  hSnapshot      : Cardinal;
  EntryParentProc: TProcessEntry32;
begin
  Result := False;
  hSnapshot := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  if hSnapshot = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    exit;
  try
    EntryParentProc.dwSize := SizeOf(EntryParentProc);
    if Process32First(hSnapshot, EntryParentProc) then
      repeat
        if CompareText(ExtractFileName(FileName), EntryParentProc.szExeFile) = 0 then
          if CompareText(ProcessFileName(EntryParentProc.th32ProcessID),  FileName) = 0 then
          begin
            Result := True;
            break;
          end;
      until not Process32Next(hSnapshot, EntryParentProc);
  finally
    CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
  end;
end;

function RegReadStr(const RegPath, RegValue: string; var Str: string;
  const RootKey: HKEY): boolean;
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  try
    Reg := TRegistry.Create;
    try
      Reg.RootKey := RootKey;
      Result      := Reg.OpenKey(RegPath, True);
      if Result then
        Str := Reg.ReadString(RegValue);
    finally
      Reg.Free;
    end;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

function RegKeyExists(const RegPath: string; const RootKey: HKEY): boolean;
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  try
    Reg := TRegistry.Create;
    try
      Reg.RootKey := RootKey;
      Result      := Reg.KeyExists(RegPath);
    finally
      Reg.Free;
    end;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;


function GetDelphiXE2LocationExeName: string;
Const
 Key = '\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\9.0';
begin
  Result:='';
    if RegKeyExists(Key, HKEY_CURRENT_USER) then
    begin
      RegReadStr(Key, 'App', Result, HKEY_CURRENT_USER);
      exit;
    end;

    if RegKeyExists(Key, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) then
      RegReadStr(Key, 'App', Result, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
end;


Var
 Bds : String;

begin
  try
     Bds:=GetDelphiXE2LocationExeName;
     if Bds<>'' then
     begin
       if  IsAppRunning(Bds) then
        Writeln('The Delphi XE2 IDE Is running')
       else
        Writeln('The Delphi XE2 IDE Is not running')
     end
     else
     Writeln('The Delphi XE2 IDE Is was not found');
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Addtional resources.
[`Detecting installed delphi versions`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/10/27/detecting-installed-delphi-versions/)

Comment: For me, in win 10 x64, i think is more secure to check this on following reg path: "\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Embarcadero\BDS\xx.xx"  is the number of delphi version, example: "\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0" in case of Rio version.

Answer (score 1):

Check DebugHook <> 0.
The down side is that currently if your app is built with packages, DebugHook will return 0.
But normally this is would be a very elegant and simple test. Works great in D2009, I just noticed that it has the package dependency bug in XE2 (http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=105365).

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).